# Закрытие окна JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, fxml

Мне нужно закрыть окно, при нажатии на кнопку в другом окне. Вот как я это попытался сделать, но выдает ошибку NullPointerException

```
public class dialogStageController extends menuStageController {
    /*...*/
    ((Stage)label.getScene().getWindow()).close();
}

public class menuStageController {
    /*...*/
    @FXML;
    protected Label label;
}
```

Оба эти контроллеры находятся в одном пакете, но разных классах.

Comment: покажите больше кода, где используется `close()`. покажите код где инициализируются `label` в классе  **dialogStageController**. классы принято называть с Большой буквы.

Comment: label нигде не инициализируеться, в fxml файле ей присвоено fx:id="label". А метод close() используется в switch().

Comment: "**label нигде не инициализируеться**" вот поэтому и **NPE**

Comment: protected Label label = new Label(): ничего не дает, таже ошибка

Comment: разуметеся, так как у этот label не принадлежит ни одной scene.

Comment: Как так не принадлежит? Я же кнопку создавал в fxml файле и загружал сцену через этот же fxml файл

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/63165/discussion-between---and-mikhail-vaysman).

Comment: вы видимо не до конца понимаете как работает наследование. поля из предка в потомк не копируются.

Comment: Можете посоветовать, как исправить ошибку?

Comment: вам надо применить паттерн MVC